# PackageManager queryIntentActivities returns empty list despite match

Tags: android, android-intent

i have two apps which depend on each other and i now want to implement a test on whether all required intents are available.

I have used the general implementation from the Android Developers blog:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/can-i-use-this-intent.html

```
public static boolean isIntentAvailable(Context context, String action) {
    final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action); 
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_DEBUG_LOG_RESOLUTION); // ADDED BY ME
    List<ResolveInfo> list =
            packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                    PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

    return list.size() > 0;
}
```

the manifest for the second app (which i check for) contains the following activity:

```
    <activity android:name="MyPackageMyAction" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter android:label="License">
         <action android:name="com.mypackage.action.myaction"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and i check for it with

boolean available = isIntentAvailable(this, "com.mypackage.action.myaction");

The log output contains this:

```
VERBOSE/IntentResolver(59): Resolving type null scheme null of intent Intent { act=com.mypackage.action.myaction flg=0x8 }
VERBOSE/IntentResolver(59): Action list: [ActivityIntentInfo{440482c0 com.mypackage.action.myaction}]
VERBOSE/IntentResolver(59): Matching against filter ActivityIntentInfo{440482c0 com.mypackage.action.myaction}
VERBOSE/IntentResolver(59):   Filter matched!  match=0x108000
VERBOSE/IntentResolver(59): Final result list:
```

So, i would normally assume that isIntentAvailable returns true if the second app is installed. However, the list returned by queryIntentActivities is always empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this your only activity in the app?

Comment: Yes, it is the only activity.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i feel very stupid now. After toying around with this problem for about a day i found the problem.

Everything was registered correctly and should have worked flawlessly, if i weren't so stupid :-). The app receiving the intent is a license key and is supposed to be hidden from the launcher. Therefore i had this line in my app:

```
pkgMgr.setApplicationEnabledSetting(PACKAGE_NAME, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

After removing it, everything worked straight away. Thanks for all your support!

Answer (score 0):

If you say that this is the only `only` activity so the category has to be `LAUNCHER`

```
 <activity android:name="MyPackageMyAction" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter android:label="License">
         <action android:name="com.mypackage.action.myaction"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Also here you can find more on `Intent`
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_LAUNCHER

Comment: Ok, but what if i do not want it to show up in the Launcher? Can't i just have it in the background as a sort of library-app?

Comment: The you should make your app run as `Service`

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html

Comment: Ok, i tried that and i still get an empty list. The filter matches